# How can I look up a username by id in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, users, uuid

The command `id` can be used to look up a user's `uid`, for example:

```
$ id -u ubuntu
1000
```

Is there a command to lookup up a username from a `uid`? I realize this can be done by looking at the `/etc/passwd` file but I'm asking if there is an existing command to to this, especially if the user executing it is not root.

I'm not looking for the *current* user's username, i.e. I am not looking for `whoami` or `logname`.

This also made me wonder if on shared web hosting this is a security feature, or am I just not understanding something correctly?

For examination, the `/etc/passwd` file from a shared web host:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin
daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin
adm:x:3:4:adm:/var/adm:/sbin/nologin
lp:x:4:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/sbin/nologin
sync:x:5:0:sync:/sbin:/bin/sync
shutdown:x:6:0:shutdown:/sbin:/sbin/shutdown
halt:x:7:0:halt:/sbin:/sbin/halt
mail:x:8:12:mail:/var/spool/mail:/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:13:news:/etc/news:
uucp:x:10:14:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/sbin/nologin
operator:x:11:0:operator:/root:/sbin/nologin
games:x:12:100:games:/usr/games:/sbin/nologin
gopher:x:13:30:gopher:/var/gopher:/sbin/nologin
ftp:x:14:50:FTP User:/var/ftp:/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:99:99:Nobody:/:/sbin/nologin
nscd:x:28:28:NSCD Daemon:/:/sbin/nologin
vcsa:x:69:69:virtual console memory owner:/dev:/sbin/nologin
pcap:x:77:77::/var/arpwatch:/sbin/nologin
rpc:x:32:32:Portmapper RPC user:/:/sbin/nologin
mailnull:x:47:47::/var/spool/mqueue:/sbin/nologin
smmsp:x:51:51::/var/spool/mqueue:/sbin/nologin
oprofile:x:16:16:Special user account to be used by OProfile:/home/oprofile:/sbin/nologin
sshd:x:74:74:Privilege-separated SSH:/var/empty/sshd:/sbin/nologin
dbus:x:81:81:System message bus:/:/sbin/nologin
avahi:x:70:70:Avahi daemon:/:/sbin/nologin
rpcuser:x:29:29:RPC Service User:/var/lib/nfs:/sbin/nologin
haldaemon:x:68:68:HAL daemon:/:/sbin/nologin
xfs:x:43:43:X Font Server:/etc/X11/fs:/sbin/nologin
avahi-autoipd:x:100:104:avahi-autoipd:/var/lib/avahi-autoipd:/sbin/nologin
named:x:25:25:Named:/var/named:/sbin/nologin
mailman:x:32006:32006::/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman/mailman:/usr/local/cpanel/bin/noshell
dovecot:x:97:97:dovecot:/usr/libexec/dovecot:/sbin/nologin
mysql:x:101:105:MySQL server:/var/lib/mysql:/bin/bash
cpaneleximfilter:x:32007:32009::/var/cpanel/userhomes/cpaneleximfilter:/usr/local/cpanel/bin/noshell
nagios:x:102:106:nagios:/var/log/nagios:/bin/sh
ntp:x:38:38::/etc/ntp:/sbin/nologin
myuser:x:1747:1744::/home/myuser:/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell
```

And here is a sample directory listing of `/tmp/`

```
drwx------  3 root     root        1024 Apr 16 02:09 spamd-22217-init/
drwxr-xr-x  2      665      664    1024 Apr  4 00:05 update-cache-44068ab4/
drwxr-xr-x  4      665      664    1024 Apr 17 15:17 update-extraction-44068ab4/
-rw-rw-r--  1      665      664   43801 Apr 17 15:17 variable.zip
-rw-r--r--  1      684      683    4396 Apr 17 07:01 wsdl-13fb96428c0685474db6b425a1d9baec
```

We can see `root` is the owner of some files, and `root` is also showing up in `/etc/passwd` , however the other users/groups all show up as numbers.

Comment: Keep in mind that more than one user may have the same UID. It's rare, but happens occasionally.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`ls` already performs that lookup. You can perform a user information lookup from the command line with [`getent passwd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36580/how-can-i-look-up-a-username-by-id-in-linux/36582#36582).

If `ls` shows a user ID instead of a user name, it's because there's no user by that name. Filesystems store user IDs, not user names. If you mount a filesystem from another system, or if a file belongs to a now-deleted user, or if you passed a numerical user ID to `chown`, you can have a file that belongs to a user ID that doesn't have a name.

On a shared host, you may have access to some files that are shared between several virtual machines, each with their user database. This is a bit weird (why share files but not the users that own them?), but it's technically possible.

Comment: I'm seeing the number instead of the name on `ls -l` if the name is over eight characters in length.

Comment: @kgrittn It might depend on the Unix variant. GNU ls shows the whole username. BusyBox ls truncates it to 8 characters (at least on the build I have here).

Comment: Try also `id -u <username>` as per [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/609648/448081) under-appreciated answer.

Answer (score 125):

You might enjoy this little ditty.

```
$ id -nu [number]
```

3.17.3-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 14 22:56:01 CET 2014 i686 GNU/Linux

I can confirm that it returns a corresponding user name, if one exists, on Arch Linux. I can also confirm that it does not work on Ubuntu when run as a normal user, although I have not tested this as the superuser. It also does not work on Alpine Linux. Maybe a security feature prevents this from working on some systems.

Comment: `id -u jimmij` => `1000`. `id -nu 1000` => `id: 1000: no such user`.

Comment: works for me, with `id --version` = `id (GNU coreutils) 8.23`

Comment: Works in FreeBSD 10.3 also.

Comment: note: this works on Red Hat/CentOS >=7 (not on Red Hat/CentOS <=6)

Comment: FYI this does *not* work on busybox/alpine linux/alpine docker images

Comment: works on Ubuntu 20.04 (probably with older versions as well)

Comment: Also works on Mint 21.1

Comment: Works in Ubuntu on WSL

Answer (score 97):

Try

```
getent passwd "$uid" | cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: If this returns nothing does that mean I don't have access to translate the id to a username?

Comment: More likely you didn`t set `"$uid"` or that uid doesn't exist.  Does `grep ":$uid:" /etc/passwd` find it?  Does `getent passwd` produce any output?

Comment: @cwd: You should always have access to translate an id to a username. For instance, `ls -l` is always doing this.

Comment: Just curious because looking at an `ls` listing on a shared host was showing numbers in the user / group name columns with ls. Perhaps it is a security precaution or jailshell thing?

Comment: @cwd More likely the shared host is using an `/etc/passwd` mounted / shared from elsewhere which wasn't mounted at the time.

Comment: @jw013 - does that mean I should look for the `etc/passwd` file or give up?

Comment: @cwd Are you sure the particular userid you are looking at exists?

Comment: @jw013 - i will update the question with more info.

Answer (score 12):

The command `id` can be used to **both** to look up UID and/or USER name

1. look up a **UID by USER**, for example:

```
    $ id -u ubuntu
    1000
```

2. look up a **USER by UID**, for example:

```
    $ id -un 1000
    ubuntu
```

If the UID or USER is not found on current machine it prints `no such user` message to `stderr`, for example:

```
$ id -un 1234
id: 1234: no such user
```

From `man id`:

> ```
> id - print real and effective user and group IDs
>    -n, --name
>           print a name instead of a number, for -ugG
>    -u, --user
>           print only the effective user ID
>    -g, --group
>           print only the effective group ID
>    -G, --groups
>           print all group IDs
> ```

Comment: Note, that the `no such user` message is printed on stderr. You get an empty string if you capture the name like `User=$(id -un 1000 2> /dev/null)`.

Comment: @RaoulSteffen good point. I have updated my original post with `stderr` output.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but here's another answer

```
awk -F: '{print $1,$3}' /etc/passwd | grep <UID>
```

Comment: Pipe to `grep` what?  (Also if you add four spaces at the start of the line, it will render it as fixed width text.)

Comment: I prefer the answer with `getent passwd`. But if parsing /etc/passwd, it would be nicer to use awk only `ID=0 ; awk -F: '{if ( $3 == '"$ID"' ) print $1}' /etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 0):

Parse /etc/passwd:

```
% awk -F: "/:$(id -u ubuntu):/{print \$1}" /etc/passwd
ubuntu
```

Comment: Unlike `getent`, this does not work if the system uses LDAP.

Comment: this doesn't work either if NIS is used or whatever other distributed authentication protocol.

Comment: @choroba : if he had a specific requirement for LDAP or NIS, he probably would have mentioned it.  My solution works on typical linux setups.

Comment: downvote beacause it's not  reliable (it could match either the user or group).

Answer (score 0):

```
id | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/.*(//;s/)$//'
```

This oneliner does the following:

- get user information
- extract the first column ("uid=ID(NAME)")
- remove anything before brackets, and the brackets themselves